# How to rename file in a general way in java?

Tags: java, windows, escaping, rename

I have two File Object `oldFile` and `newFile` and I would like to exchange the corresponding file names. So I *rename* `oldFile` to a `tmpFile` name first. I get the oldFile's absolute path and append ".bak" for it:

```
String tmpFile = oldFile.getAbsolutePath().toString()+".bak";
oldFile.renameTo(new File(tmpFile));
```

The problem is that tmpFile contains the raw string of path,while the constructor of `File` class treat the '\' as the escape.So the tmpFile may be **"D:\oldfile.java.bak"**,however what the constructor need is

```
new File("D:\\oldfile.java.bak");
```

How can I deal with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to escape the escapes with `.replace("\", "\\")` but if you have to do that then realize you don't have to use `\` on Windows. Java supports `/` just as fine and it doesn't have these problems. You can do `replace("\", "/")` and it works just as well.

You also need to read and understand how to create new files in Java. [`File.createNewFile()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createNewFile%28%29) is required to be called. Just creating a `File` object with the constructor doesn't actual create a file on the filesystem nor does it guarantee that a file at that location exists.

Answer (score 3):

The constructor of File does NOT treat `\` as escape. You need to escape `\` with `\` in a string **literal**. The String literal `"\\"` contains a single character: `'\'`.

```
String path = "D:\\oldFile";
System.out.println(path); // prints D:\oldFile
File f = new File(path);
System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath()); // prints D:\oldFile
```

Comment: In other words, Hongxu Chen, there is no problem with your original approach.

Comment: The problem is that the oldFile's name is not available. I followed Jarrod Roberson's advice `tmpFile = tmpFile.replace("\", "\\")`;However it fails to compile.

Comment: How could a file name not be available? What does that mean?

Comment: @JB Nizet I mean the file name is not written first, and only the file Object like oldFile exists.

Comment: I still don't understand. The above code is there to show you that the backslash is not escaped. But of course you don't need to print anything.